# Finale software: How can I add a measure within a numbered repeat ending?

Tags: software, repeats, finale

I'm trying to expand a repeat ending (ending 1) that is currently 1 measure to four measures, but if I try to insert measures they always get inserted outside of the repeat symbols.

A screenshot of the current situation:

[image: excerpt showing repeat with volta brackets]

Comment: However have you tried removing the first repeat and second ending, expand the first ending, reinsert the second ending then insert, and then place the repeat? Not a very efficient way but for all I know the software has rules on it that prevents any new measures to be created. Edit -- I read finale in its literal definition not as in the piece of software sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution seems to be to use the repeat tool to remove the endings, then to add the measure, then to use the repeat tool to add the endings as you want them.

These are the steps (using the repeat tool):

1. Highlight both the first and second endings
2. Right click -> Delete, to remove your endings completely.
3. Do whatever you need to do (i.e. add your measures).
4. Select the measures you want to be in the first ending.
5. Repeat Menu -> Create Ending
6. This should default to Ending Numbers = 1 and Create Backward Repeat Bar = true (see photo), Click OK.  This will create your first ending and repeat sign.
7. Highlight the measures you want in the Second ending, Repeat Menu -> Create Ending.
8. This time it should default to Ending Number = 2 and Create Backward Repeat Bar = false.  Accept these defaults, click OK.

Now you should have the repeats as you want them.

[image]